# Form в Laravel 5.7, как отследить какая кнопка была нажата в контроллере?

Tags: laravel, form

Есть форма, содержащая 3 Кнопки Submit. Можно ли, в контроллере, отследить какая кнопка была нажата?
Пробовал с помощью `if ($request->Block) {}`, но ничего не вышло.

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
@csrf
   <div class="card-header">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" name="Block">Block</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="Unlock">Unlock</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger delete" name="Del">Del</button>
</div>

</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Select 
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="All" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                </th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Date Online</th>
                <th scope="col">Date Register</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>                                
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="{{$user->id}}" name="selectuser{{$user->id}}" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                </td>
                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->last_entrance}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->created_at}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
        </tbody>  
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В форме сделайте следующие изменения:

```
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" name="submit_key" value="block">Block</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="submit_key" value="unlock">Unlock</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger delete" name="submit_key" value="del">Del</button>
    </div>
```

В контроллере это можно будет обработать следующим образом:

```
switch(request('submit_key')) {
    case 'block': // нажата кнопка Block
    break;
    case 'unlock': // нажата кнопка Unlock
    break;
    case 'del': // нажата кнопка Del
    break;
}
```